# How to save console output still showing it

Tags: linux, console, telnet, pipe

I need to troubleshoot a telnet session and send save it's results to another person. When I use redirection I save the contents of my session,  but I'm not able to see it on console.

How to pipe current terminal/program and still show it on current console.

When I use the command below I can save the program's output,  but I'm not able to see it on console.

```
telnet ADDRESS PORT >> myoutputfile
```

I could use a telnet output option,  I'm looking for a command independent way to do it.

The question is specific for a telnet session,  but applies to any other command,  including those that don't have a "save output to file option".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `tee`:-

```
telnet ADDRESS PORT | tee -a myoutputfile
```

This copies output to both standard output and the specified file name, and the `-a` option appends, just as your `>>` redirection did.

Comment: A small issue: the ^] sequence (scape character) doesn't work when using tee.

Comment: That's probably because `telnet` makes that transformation in its output when it's writing to `stdout`, which it isn't in this case. You could try appending `| cat -v` to the command, but this will display lines only when there is a new-line in the output.

Comment: This didnt work for me (windows PS) - file is empty

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick to use the error output as a second buffer to output to 2 devices.

Your command would be:

```
telnet ADDRESS PORT >&2 2>>myoutputfile
```

This appends the output to myoutputfile and also writes whatever comes out to console.

`>&2`: This copies output from stream 1 (console) to stream 2 (error)

`2>>`: This makes sure everything from stream 2 is being sent to the file.

If you do not want to risk having errorlogging added to the file, change the 2 to 3 in both rows. (`>&3 3>>file`)

EDIT: I just noticed the linux tag. This is written for Windows, but it might still work.

Comment: It makes sense,  but doesn't work with a telnet session (I type the telnet commands,  but I can't read the response)

Comment: `>&2` redirects output: it doesn't copy it. Your command has the same effect as the questioner's, except that error messages also go to the file instead of being displayed on the console.

Comment: @AFH on windows the & means copy the stream. I tested it and on windows it does work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm so used to Linux syntax these days.